# Rails ActiveRecord Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, model-associations

Okay, so here is my question.  I have a 3 different models, People, Roles, Client, and Store.  Clients have many Stores and can also have many people.  Stores have many people.  People have various roles.  1 Person can work at multiple stores, and they may have different roles at each store.

For example.  Joe may be an assistant manager at one store and a manager at another store.  What I would like to be able to do is pull the correct roles by doing something like

```
Store.find(1).people.find(1).roles
```

(would return 'assistant manager' for example) or

```
Store.find(2).people.find(1).roles
```

(would return 'manager' for example).  Is this possible to do in ActiveRecord?

I've created a table :roles_people which has the following definition:

```
create_table :roles_people, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role
      t.references :person
      t.references :store
      t.references :client
end
```

However i can't figure out how to get associations to work properly using this table.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: The issue that i'm having is being able to filter the roles of the person based on the Store he/she belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class People
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :store_roles
end

class Roles
  has_many :store_roles
end

class StoreRole
  belongs_to :role
  belongs_to :people
  belongs_to :store
end

class Client
  has_many :stores
  has_many :people
end

class Store
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :store_roles
  has_many :roles, :through => :store_roles
end
```

Assume that all of those classes inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` ;)

You're going to need to setup the migration and database structure to mirror these relationships.  For each `belongs_to` there is an `:object_id` field on the table reference the appropriate table's id.

Your query is going to need to look something like:

```
Store.find(1).roles.find(:all, :conditions => ["store_roles.person_id = ?", 1])
```

I would probably add a method to the store model to make this a little easier:

```
def roles_for(person_id)
  roles.find(:all, :conditions => ["store_roles.person_id = ?", person_id])
end
```

This way you can find the roles using:

```
Store.find(1).roles_for(1)
```

Or, better yet:

```
def self.roles_for(store_id, person_id)
  Role.find(:all, :joins => :store_roles, :conditions => ["store_roles.store_id = ? AND store_roles.person_id = ?", store_id, person_id])
end
```

Which changes our finder to:

```
Store.roles_for(1, 1)
```

I would say that this last method is the most ideal since it causes only a single query, while each of the other options execute two queries to the database per role look-up (one to find the store, and one to get the roles for a person_id).  Of course if you already have the Store object instantiated then it's not a big deal.

Hopefully this answer was sufficient :)

Comment: Excellent!  Worked out great!  Thanks so much everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is has_many :through

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles_people
  has_many :roles, :through => :roles_people
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles_people
  has_many :people, :through => roles_people
end
```

You'll also need to add relationships to RolePerson:

```
class RolePerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :role
end
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Very helpful link [@blog.hasmanythrough.com](http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2007/1/15/basic-rails-association-cardinality)

Comment: You should explain here that they need to create a RolePerson model too, which acts as the intermediary model.

Comment: @ryan-bigg Thanks for the advice! Long time listener, first time poster.

Answer (score 0):

`has_and_belongs_to_many` is your friend.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

That way, you can get all roles the person has by calling `Person.roles.all`. The resulting query is going to use the `people_roles` table. You can also use `has_many :through` but have to build model classes for the join table yourself and maintain all the associations yourself. Sometimes it's necessary, sometimes it's not. Depends on the complexity of your actual model.

Comment: I tried that.  However, the roles are store specific.  So if i want to only return a role for that specific store, i'm still unable to do so.  For instance, I have 'ACME Warehouse' with 'John Doe' as a 'Store Manager'.  'John Doe' also works for 'ABC Foods' as an 'assistant manager'.  If i query Store.where(:name => "ABC Foods").people.where(:name => "John Doe").roles, it should only return 'assistant manager' and not 'Store Manager'.  If i query for acme warehouse instead it should return 'store manager' and nothing else.

Comment: Then you have to `use has_many :through` as your association between stores and people are enriched with the role property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your table name in `people_roles` and you can drop both store and client references:

```
create_table :roles_people, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :role
  t.references :person
  t.references :store
end
```

Role is something that belongs only to people.

You then need to use has_and_belongs_to_many:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :stores, :through => :people_roles
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  has_many :people, :through => :people_roles
end
```

Than you can query:

```
Store.find(1).people.find(1).roles
```

Comment: I understand, but in my case the role belongs to both the person and the store.  Lets say you work 2 part time jobs.  Both are at gas stations.  At one gas station you are an assistant manager, at another you are just a cashier.  I need to be able to figure out which role you have at which gas station.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. You can't do exactly what you wanted, but i guess we can come close. 
For completeness, i am going to recap your datastructure:

```
class Client
  has_many :stores
end

class Store
  has_many :people
  has_many :roles
end

class Person
  has_many :roles
  has_many :stores
end

class Role
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :person
end
```

You see that the role does not need the link to the client, because that can be found straightaway from the store (i am assuming a stored is "owned" by only one client).

Now a `role` is linked both to a `person` and a `store`, so a person can have different roles per store.
And to find these in a clean way, i would use a helper function:

```
class Person
  has_many :roles
  has_many :stores

  def roles_for(store)
    roles.where("store_id=?", store.id)
  end
end
```

So you can't write something like

```
store.people.first.roles
```

to get the roles of the first person working for that store.
But writing something like:

```
store.people.first.roles_for(store)
```

is not too hard i hope.

The reason why this is so is because in the context of the person (-> `store.people.first`) we no longer have any notion of the store (how we got there).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Close!  Only issue is that if another store has an assistant manager, this query won't work because both stores 'own' the assistant manager role.  So your query would still return assistant manager for a user that may not be an assistant manager at that store.  I should also mention that i need to use HABTM if possible, since the people table may contain people not associated with any store (but we don't care about those.)

Comment: Did you try that? That is weird. As i wrote it, you start from the set of `roles` a person has, and it will select those that are linked to the correct store. So it could not return a role from another person. Could you show your current code? And indeed: you should be using HABTM.