# Join two tables in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have two tables.
1. "SharedInfo" with 4 attributes: id, info_name, description, type_id
2. "Type" with 3 attributes: id, type_name, code

The relationship is: "SharedInfo" belongs_to "Type", "Type" has_many "SharedInfo". Foreign key is: type_id.

I want to jion 2 tables and select info_name, description, type_id, type_name, code
How can I do it in RoR application(Controller)

I edit my question for more specific:

In controller I want to retrieve a instances @instance that has all attributes of table "SharedInfo" and attributes "code" of table "Type" base on "type_id" attribute.
(The @instance have 'id', 'info_name', 'description', 'type_id', 'code' attributes)

Comment: How are the two tables related? What's the attribute both of the tables share?

Comment: Jayesh: Yes, table "SharedInfo" have the attribute type_id, which is the foreign key references to table "Type"

Comment: Does anyone know about this? I really need help.

Comment: Have you looked at Rails Associations? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association

Comment: I read it, but I don't know how to apply it in my case. Can you suggest me some hints?

Comment: Because I need to convert it to json and user in javascript, I need create an instance that includes all attributes of SharedInfo and attribute "code" of table "Type" in controller first, and convert in to json in View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved my problem:
By Using this:

```
@locations = SharedInfo.select("shared_infos.info_name, shared_infos.description, shared_infos.type_id, types.type_name, types.code").joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN types ON types.id = shared_infos.type_id")
```

Hope that help people, who have the problem like me.
Thank all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.joins()`
Try this assume that `id = 1` for example:

```
select("si.info_name, si.description, si.type_id, t.type_name, t.code")
.from("SharedInfo AS si ON t.type_id = si.type_id")
.joins("Type AS t ON si.type_id = t.type_id")
.where("si.id = 1")
```

Comment: I tried. But it's not work in my case. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: can I get the schema of your database?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved my problem. Let's look at my result below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use `Active Record Associations` to do this.
`SharedInfo has_many Type` and `Type belongs_to SharedInfo`. Using this you can do join query on both the tables.

As far as your later part of converting it to json and displaying in view, you could render the Active Record object to json and use it.

Read more about Active Record Associations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association). You can also refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228066/277553) for examples.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for spending time to help me. I'll try.